# Connect to cosmos db from local code using DefaultAzureCredential

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-cosmosdb, rbac

I've written a script in Typescript to get some item from a Cosmos DB container. Now I am using the DefaultAzureCredential to authenticate. For some reason I'm getting back a 403 stating I don't have sufficient permissions. That seems strange to me since I'm the administrator.

I'm executing the script locally right now for testing purposes. I'm using VS Code and I'm logged into Azure using their extension. I can see my Azure resources from VS Code, so I think that's going fine.

I have below roles as of right now:

- Cosmos DB Account Reader Role
- Managed Application Operator Role
- Owner
- Reader

That should be sufficient right? Am I missing something?

Below is my script, which I think is nothing out of the ordinary.

```
import { CosmosClient } from "@azure/cosmos";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

const client = new CosmosClient({
  endpoint:
    process.env.DATABASE_ENDPOINT,
  aadCredentials: credential,
});

export async function getItem(
  database_name: string,
  container_name: string,
  id: string
) {
  const { resource } = await client
    .database(database_name)
    .container(container_name)
    .item(id, id)
    .read();

  return resource;
}
```

And an excerpt of the error I'm getting:
ErrorResponse: Request blocked by Auth {db name} : Request is blocked because principal [xxxxxxxxxxx] does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource [/]. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmos-native-rbac.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are doing auth with Azure AD right ? Make sure you register the app and give it correct permissions. Or better said give correct RBAC permissions to service principal = your app.

**[EDIT]**

> To authenticate Azure SDK clients within web browsers, we offer the InteractiveBrowserCredential, which can be set to use redirection or popups to complete the authentication flow. It's necessary to create an Azure App Registration in the Azure portal for your web application first.

FIY -> [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-node-latest#authenticate-the-client-in-browsers)